# using re to grab all instances of values between parenthesis

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm using python's re module to grab all instances of values between the
opening and closing parenthesis.

```
i.e.  (A)way(Of)testing(This)
```

would produce a list:

```
   ['A', 'Of', 'This']
```

I took a look at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108561/how-to-exclude-a-character-from-a-regex-group) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697934/python-re-compile-and-re-findall).

This is my code:

```
import re


sentence = "(A)way(Of)testing(This)is running (it)"

res = re.compile(r".*\(([a-zA-Z0-9|^)])\).*", re.S)
for s in re.findall(res, sentence):
    print(s)
```

What I get from this is:

```
it
```

Then I realized I was only capturing just one character, so I used

```
res = re.compile(r".*\(([a-zA-Z0-9-|^)]*)\).*", re.S)
```

But I still get `it`

I've always struggled with regex.  My understanding of my search string
is as follows:

- `.*`                 (any character)
- `\(`                 (escapes the opening parenthesis)
- `(`                  (starts the grouping)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-|^)]*`    (set of characters allowed : a-Z, A-Z, 0-9, - *EXCEPT the ")" )
- `)`                  (closes the grouping)
- `\)`                 (escapes the closing parenthesis)
- `.*`                 (anything else)

So in theory it should go through `sentence` and once it encounters a `(`,
it should copy the contents up until it encounters a `)`, at which point it should
store that into one group.  It then proceeds through the `sentence`.

I even used the following:

```
  res = re.compile(r".*\(([a-z|A-Z|0-9|-|^)]*)\).*", re.S)
```

But it still returns an `it`.

Any help greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the pattern without the `.*` and the `^` and `)` and only use the character class.

The `.*` part matches any character, and as the part between parenthesis is only once in the pattern you will capture only 1 group.

In your explanation about this part `[a-zA-Z0-9-|^)]*` the character class does not rule out the `)` using `|^)`. It will just match either a `|` `^` or `)` char.

If you want to use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), the `^` should be at the start of the character class like `[^` but that is not necessary here as you can specify what do you want to match instead of what you don't want to match.

```
\(([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9-]*` Optionally repeat matching one of the listed ranges a-zA-Z0-9 or `-`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G4Jjkf/1)

You don't need the `re.S` as there is no dot in the pattern that should match a newline.

```
import re

sentence = "(A)way(Of)testing(This)is running (it)"
res = re.compile(r"\(([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\)")
print(re.findall(res, sentence))
```

Output

```
['A', 'Of', 'This', 'it']
```